# Fail to register in Jmx in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

While configure JNDI data source in spring boot embedded server,  the below error is populating, `Null pointer exception for  DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance`

Comment: Thanks in advance....

Comment: Need more details, configuration code, other pertinent details